# TypeError: Dimension value must be integer or None or have an __index__ method, got value 'TensorShape([None, 16])'

Tags: python, api, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to write the below code, but getting this error continuously. Please help me with this.

```
review_sequence = tf.keras.Input(shape = (None, ))
embedding_sequence = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=max_index_value+1, output_dim=embedding_dim, input_shape=tuple(review_sequence.shape), mask_zero = False)(review_sequence)
average_embedding = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(embedding_sequence),
positive_probability = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(average_embedding)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = review_sequence, outputs = positive_probability)
```

Although if I use the Sequential layer instead of the functional keras API to write the same model, it works perfectly fine.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim = max_index_value+1, output_dim=embedding_dim, mask_zero=False),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoudn't be using `input_shape` in the second layer here:
 `embedding_sequence = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=max_index_value+1, output_dim=embedding_dim,` **input_shape=tuple(review_sequence.shape)**`, mask_zero = False)(review_sequence)`  - the input shape is defined by the previous layer (`review_sequence`)